# Automate cURL to run through a list of ID's

Tags: bash, curl, activecampaign

I am attempting to run through a list of 10 contact ID's every ten minutes with cURL

This is the code I am trying to run

```
curl --request POST \
    --url https://youraccountname.api-us1.com/api/3/contactAutomations \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'api-token: test' \
    --data '
{
     "contactAutomation": {
          "contact": THE VARIABLE,
          "automation": 23
     }
}'
```

The list of contact variables could just be line items in a text file.

Is this something a bash script with cron could handle - and it just deleted the 10 IDs it runs?

Or is this something I would need to use python and a database to run?

This is really a one off thing - so a cron with a script would be easiest since it doesn't need to be used more than one time through.

Comment: It's easy to substitute a variable into a string in a shell script. Why wouldn't you be able to it in a bash script? What problem did you run into when you tried? Remember that variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with `python`?

Comment: @Barmar how could I run through a list of variables

Comment: `while read contactid ; do ... done < contactlist.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constant list of IDs:

```
for id in 123 456 555 777
do
    curl --request POST \
        --url https://youraccountname.api-us1.com/api/3/contactAutomations \
        --header 'Accept: application/json' \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --header 'api-token: test' \
        --data "
    {
         \"contactAutomation\": {
              \"contact\": $id,
              \"automation\": 23
         }
    }"
done
```